# Building a Restful CRUD API with Node.js with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i get the error:
{
"message": "Note content can not be empty"
}

The MongoDB is running and if i start $ node server.js, i get the messages:
Server is listening on port 3000
Successfully connected to the database

if i delete the following lines in note.controller.js. The Response-Status are 200-OK :

```
//return res.status(400).send({
// message: "Note content can not be empty"
// });
```

but the 'titel' contains the default content: "title": "Untitled Note".

I guess, it's a problem with the Middleware/ Mongoose`enter code here`.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

So, this error occurred to me when I followed the same tutorial, and the reason being that I was not experienced in using the Postman application.

The issue occurs when you choose the body as **raw** in the POST method by keeping the format of body as **Text**

For it to work properly, since the date should be in JSON format to be written into MongoDB as per the server configuration, we need to **choose the raw body format as Json**, as shown in the image below.

[image]